# Keep leading zeroes

Tags: arduino

I am storing values of time as a long on an Arduino. However, times before 10am have leading 0, e.g. 9.30am would be 093000.

I am aware this stores the times as octal values but I want to keep these as decimal as I want to compare this against other times and to be able to add 24 hours, done by adding 240000 in this format, if the time passes 0.

I have seen solutions to similar problems, but the solutions only help with printing the value, whereas I want to be able to add to the value.

Comment: Why do you need the leading zero for addition? (Also what makes you believe that its not being stored?)

Comment: For working with times, try checking out `time.h`. Leading zeros are only relevant when *displaying* the data - this is down to how you format the output, not the data

Comment: Leading 0s have no affect on the value of a number (besides being the syntax for octal notation in `C` e.g. `010 == 8`). Why do you care about leading 0s if you aren't printing the value somewhere?

Comment: Integer values in C don't _have_ any way to store, or not store, leading zeroes. They're just numbers. Leading zeroes are _only_ relevant to formatting.

Comment: (Voted to close because you believe you have a programming problem, but the only real problem is that you don't understand numbers. If you try writing an MCVE which somehow behaves differently without leading zeroes, you'll see this).

Comment: He doesn't understand numbers as represented in C. If we disqualified questions on the grounds that the questioner doesn't understand something, there would be no questions.

Comment: Arduino is **not** C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading zero = octal is only a thing in C source code. If you write

```
long aTime = 073000;
```

you will get the number represented in octal by `073000` The easy workaround is to omit the leading zero.

```
long aTime = 73000;
```

You just put it back when you format it as a string:

```
printf("%06ld", aTime);
```

The format specifier `%06ld` adds leading zeros up to the field width of 6.

But actually you don't want to do this, you want to use a Unix `time_t` to store your times e.g.

```
time_t aTime = now();
```

And for formatting for display, the Arduino [has a library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Time.html) to get the various components out.